# How can I fix the Localizable.strings group in my Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, internationalization, localizable.strings

When I zipped and unzipped a project in a new location, for some reason Localizable.strings did not make the journey. The entry for it in the Xcode project is red.

The folders are in the project folder where they should be (en.lproj and es-419.lproj). I don't understand why the project broke, just by copying it and unzipping it.

How can I repair the Xcode project?

[image]

Comment: What is the swift tag for?

Answer (score 0):

I had renamed my project folder, and that broke Localizable.strings.

Then I unzipped the file again, and copied over the unzipped project folder without renaming it, the project was unbroken.

I am curious, two other files in the folder, a .swift file and .txt file, were similarly broken, in a very large and complex project, and no others. I don't know what the broken links in the project had in common.